# In Android Studio, how do I create a folder for project documentation?

Tags: android-studio, project

In Eclipse, I had some folders in the project root that were not code - containing text files with notes about the project, Photoshop files for artwork and so on.  Having migrated to Android Studio, these extra folders in the project root are not visible in the Project navigation pane - I only see the app folder and Gradle Scripts.

Is there some way to create a non-code folder that is visible in the Project pane but that is outside the app module?

I thought "Create New Module" in the Project Structure dialogue might do it, but it only offers me templates for modules that contain Android code.

--- EDIT ---

Thanks to @SvdTweel's answer I've stumbled across something that *seems* to do what I want:

- switch to the Project view
- create the documentation folder in the project root
- right-click it and select Mark Directory as>Resources Root
- switch back to the Android view and you see a new folder named "resources"

Will this have any adverse effects?  Is this folder still ignored when building the app module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Project Structure you can switch from Android to Project.

The default Android view structures and minimalizes the directories and files so that you as a developer can easier navigate through your project.

The Project view shows everything just as you would see when you browse it with your file explorer on your OS.

I think that is what you search for to create files and directories in the root of the project.
[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that does let me create the folder.  When I switch back to the Android view I still can't see it though - is there a way to modify the Android view to add one or more extra folders to it?

Comment: Unfortunally I don't think there is a configuration for by default, maybe there is a plugin for Intellij/Android Studio where you could modify it. But otherwise the Android view only shows Android related files. If you worked with Eclipse and Android before then you only had the project view right? In that case you also could keep Android Studio in the Project view without switching back.

Comment: Eclipse hides IDE working files (.classpath, .project) whereas Project view shows them (.gradle, .idea).  Android view does have some nice improvements, but I miss being able to get to my documentation without switching windows.  Needing to switch views doesn't seem much better than what I am already doing, which is keeping a Windows Explorer window open on the documentation folder outside of Android Studio.  I'll keep this question open for a couple more days before accepting your answer, just in case there is a way to add a new folder in the project root to the Android view.  Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this solution together with marking the new directory as a Resources Root for a couple of days and it seems to be working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the doc files in the `test/resources` folder. This is clumsy, but it makes them visible in the Android view while keeping them out of the build.

Bonus: code completion when editing Markdown code samples using the JetBrains Markdown plugin.